# Best way to find the required file with path list in the directory in groovy

Tags: groovy

I need to fetch the files which matches with the file name in the given directory
Suggest me the best way to fetch the matched list with the actual path of the files.

The result should be a list

```
String directory = "/home/xxx/yyy"
File  currentDir = new File(directory)
final String expectedFile = "expectedFile.txt";

        currentDir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) {
            if(it.name.equals(expectedFile)) {
                println it
            }
        }
```

Comment: Isn't the above code working?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example, which uses a regular expression to find all `.txt` files in `/foo/bar/xyz` and its subdirectories:

```
String directory = "/foo/bar/xyz"
File  currentDir = new File(directory)
final String expectedFilePattern = /.*\.txt/
def files = []

currentDir.eachFileRecurse(groovy.io.FileType.FILES) {
    if (it.name ==~ expectedFilePattern) { 
        files << it
    }
}

files.each { println it.absolutePath }
```